# Remove item from reference Array (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a User model that holds an array of references to other users:

```
friends          : [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' } ]
```

How can I remove an item from this list? This is what I'm trying so far:

```
var index = user.friends.indexOf(friend_id);
```

This properly gets the index of the item. Now I'm trying a splice:

```
user.friends = user.friends.splice(index, 1);
user.save();
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. Any advice?

Comment: This should work, did u check if friend_id really is in that array ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an issue with the way you're using `splice()`. You are using it  and expecting `user.friends` to be the resulting array. However, `splice()` actually changes the **context** array and returns the deleted items. So essentially, `user.friends` now holds the deleted items rather than the modified items.

To fix this, just remove the assignment when you perform `splice()`:

`user.friends.splice(index, 1);`

instead of how you have it currently:

`user.friends = user.friends.splice(index, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the filter method on object,
I'm not sure about the syntax but it should be something like:

```
console.log(filter(Schema.Types.ObjectId, function(friends) {
  return !(user.friends == friend_id);
}
));
```

let me know !!

Comment: Work perfectly with mongoose 5.7.7. The only way work for me. Thanks!